# I'm trying to implement undo/redo with redux -- Why does my object clone get updated when I update the original object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here is the problem function in my redux slice:

```
setButtonBackgroundColor: (state, action) => {
      const btn = state.list.present.find(
        (btn) => btn.id === action.payload.id
      );
      let copy = Object.assign({}, btn);
      state.list.past = [...state.list.past, copy];
      btn.style.backgroundColor = action.payload.backgroundColor;
    }
```

When btn.style.backgroundColor is updated, so is copy. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you're only making a _shallow_ copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(btn)) did the trick.